# SwipeGesture not working when zoomed in

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a SubView within a UIScrollView. Within the SubView, I have an image with multiple buttons. I have two finger Swipe gestures coded so that users can swipe up, down, left, or right to pop another view onto the navigation controller. When the view is loaded, I can easily swipe and it performs as expected. However, when I zoom in or all the way out, the two finger swipe gestures are ignored. If I get lucky, sometimes it will get recognized when zoomed in/out, but I can not allow that behavior for my users. Can anyone please help? Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the code which you have already tried?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figured it out using both the Gesture recognizer delegate method requireGestureRecognizerToFail. I needed two finger swipes in all directions. I created a pan gesture recognizer first and set the appropriate amount of minimum and maximum touches. You have to set the delegate of the pan gesture to self and also make sure you set the requireGestureRecognizerToFail to each swipe gesture. Don't forget to also pass the swipe gesture collection in shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(image.frame.size.width, image.frame.size.height);
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4;
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1;
    scrollView.delegate = self;

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *TwoFingerPanGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(HandlePanGesture:)];
    TwoFingerPanGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches=2;
    TwoFingerPanGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches=2;
    [TwoFingerPanGesture setDelegate:self];
    [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:TwoFingerPanGesture];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *TwoFingerSwipeDownGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(HandleSwipeGesture:)];
    TwoFingerSwipeDownGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
    TwoFingerSwipeDownGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2   ;
    [TwoFingerPanGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:TwoFingerSwipeDownGesture];
    [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:TwoFingerSwipeDownGesture];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *TwoFingerSwipeUpGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(HandleSwipeGesture:)];
    TwoFingerSwipeUpGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
    TwoFingerSwipeUpGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
    [TwoFingerPanGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:TwoFingerSwipeUpGesture];
    [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:TwoFingerSwipeUpGesture];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *TwoFingerSwipeLeftGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(HandleSwipeGesture:)];
    TwoFingerSwipeLeftGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    TwoFingerSwipeLeftGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
    [TwoFingerPanGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:TwoFingerSwipeLeftGesture];
    [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:TwoFingerSwipeLeftGesture];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *TwoFingerSwipeRightGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(HandleSwipeGesture:)];
    TwoFingerSwipeRightGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    TwoFingerSwipeRightGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
    [TwoFingerPanGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:TwoFingerSwipeRightGesture];
    [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:TwoFingerSwipeRightGesture];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    // Either just return YES to allow your cell's gesture recognizer
    // to work simultaneously with all other recognizers:
    //return YES;

    // Or you can decide whether your cell's pan gesture recognizer should
    // recognize simultaneously with otherGestureRecognizer. For example,
    // you could get a reference to your collection view's panGestureRecognizer
    // and only return YES if otherGestureRecognizer is equal to that recognizer:
    return otherGestureRecognizer == scrollView.gestureRecognizers;
}
```